# Applet jar reload problems

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet, signed-applet

Applet jar was loaded first  time successfully in  Web browser using netbeans. After that I reload my webpage - it shows error  "Error  clicks for details..."  and  I am 
configured latest Java version.

How to get the applet jar to load successfully on page refresh?

Comment: *"..clicks for details..."* What were the details?  Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: BTW - given this is a Q&A site where people expect answers, it pays to ask a question! I have 'guessed' a question above, if that's not the question you want to ask, make an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35957699/edit) & add one.

Comment: And also: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).